# Samba share unreachable on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, smb

I have a remote Samba share with my web hosting provider. I am unable to access it using OS X 10.8.2, while accessing it from a Windows 7 VM inside the OS X works fine. On OS X, I use "connect to server..." and try to access `smb://servername/sharename`. The operation times out with an unspecified error.

According to the hosting provider, this is because Apple dropped native Samba support in 10.7, and started using its own implementation of the protocol instead. This new implementation seems to have compatibility problems that prevent connecting to this particular remote share.

[This Apple forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4145388?start=180&tstart=0) seems to confirm that users are having issues since OS X 10.7.

- Is there a simple way to get back native Samba support in 10.8.2? I myself am not afraid of some command line tinkering but I want to share this samba drive with a number of colleagues. I wouldn't want to have to make deep changes to their OS Xes.
- Alternatively, do any third-party tools exist that add  support for "original" Samba?

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing here, as my G4 quicksilver can't run OS X 10.8, but the confil file may require SMB signing and NTLM v2, try lowering the authentication level, and turning off SMB signing and let me know if that resolves your issue. In previous versions it was smb.conf

You may want to also try:
http://eduo.info/apps/smbup

http://jsddevelopment.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/wdtv-live-and-samba.html

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to use back slashes \ for smb urls instead of forward slashes // used for afp.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You do *not* use backslashes for connecting to any share type when connecting via Finder (command-K).